# cellfun error : Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell

```
field1 = 'f1';  value1 = [1 2];
field2 = 'f2';  value2 = {1, 2, 32, 'text'};
field3 = 'f3';  value3 = [pi pi.^2];
field4 = 'f4';  value4 = [1 2 3];
s = struct(field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3,field4,value4);

x = cellfun(@(u) numel(u), value2); %%% WORKS FINE
x = cellfun(@(u) numel(u), s.f2); %%%% THROWS ERROR
x = cellfun(@(u) numel(u.f2), s); %%%% THROWS ERROR
```

Can someone give explaination why the last 2 lines throws error? The error is :

```
Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of `cellfun` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) says  (emphasis mine):

> Apply function to ***each cell*** in ***cell array***.

You don't have cell arrays in your second and third usage of `cellfun` and hence those do not work.

---

In your second usage of `cellfun` i.e `x = cellfun(@(u) numel(u), s.f2);`
`s.f2` returns a comma separated list. To get the same result using `cellfun`, you can concatenate the comma separated list in a cell array and then `cellfun` like this:

```
x = cellfun(@(u) numel(u), {s.f2});
```

---

In the third usage of `cellfun`, you are inputting a vector structure. In this case to get the same result, you can apply `arrayfun` more conveniently like this:

```
x = arrayfun(@(u) numel([u.f2]), s);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the 3rd call, the struct `s` you created is called a "[Nonscalar Struct Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-multiple-elements-of-a-nonscalar-struct-array.html)", because your f2 element is a cell array of non-scalar elements. Aside from the solution provided by @Sandar, you can also do

```
x=cellfun(@numel, {s(:).f2})
```